# Delete stack in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Let's say we have this screen navigation case :

other previous screens -> A ->  B -> C -> D

Now that we're in the Screen D, how can we go back directly to screen B and erase the screens D and C from the stack?

I'm using navigation.navigate(B, params), but then in the screen B when I click on the back button I'm back to screen D. The intent is to go to A.

Edit:
I'm trying to use the reset action :

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [previousNavigationActions, navigateActionToScreenB],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

How do I get the previous navigation actions from the navigation state?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
    key: 'C'   // if you want to go back to B
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction)
```

As `key`, you have to use the screen after the one you want to navigate to, see [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Back).

You can also try to manually [reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset) the history, but the back-method above would be the easier and more clean solution.

Comment: I thinking about using reset. Knowing that there are screens before A, how do I get the actions from the state so I can use them in my resetAction ?

Comment: I think you'll have to mess around with `router.getStateForAction`, which gives you access to `state.routes` (see https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/replace-a-screen-using-react-navigation-a503eab207eb and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/routers/), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user3574857 Please consider accepting the answer or provide some more info about your current problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I managed to use getStateForAction and manually manipulates the routes and index I want to delete from my stack

Answer (score 1):

From [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html#calling-dispatch-or-navigate-on-app-container) plugin v 3.9.0 I have used following code which removes all back stack and navigate to the screen.

```
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: '<<YOUR ROUTE NAME>>' })]
  })
  )
```